# Need PowerShell script to filtering the excel data

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter the data contains in excel. but it showing error.

```
Import-Csv -Path "D:\Excel\Data\List.csv" -Header "EventID", "TimeCreated", "Computer", "TargetUserName", "SubjectUserName", "HOSTName", "Filename" | 
        Where-Object {[INT]$_.TargetUserName -eq 122388} | 
        Select-Object "EventID", "TimeCreated", "Computer", "TargetUserName", "SubjectUserName", "HOSTName", "Filename" | 
        Export-Csv "D:\Excel\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[image: Excel Input data]

[image: Error while executing]

Comment: By using the `-header` parameter you adding an extra header to the already existing header. Therefore the existing header becomes the first row where the top cell in the `TargetUserName` contains the *string* `"TargetUserName"` which can't be converted to an integer. Long story short: **lose the `-header` parameter.**

Comment: Additional note: the operand at the left hand side in a comparison operation is leading for type casting. In other words, by simply swapping the operands (`122388 -eq $_.TargetUserName`) you will do a number (integer) compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely getting read in as a string instead of an integer. Do an equality test against a string instead.

Try replace `Where-Object {[INT]$_.TargetUserName -eq 122388}` with `Where-Object {$_.TargetUserName -eq "122388"}`

Comment: How to do the equality test. I am new for the shell scripting. kindly help me @Toby Boulton

Comment: @Arunkumar check updated answer